# Does python's new 'pip wheel' have any support for building wheels for the dependencies listed in tests_requires?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-wheel

I use setuptools 'tests_require' to specify dependencies required for testing my package.

```
tests_require - http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords
```

I have begun using wheel packaging

```
http://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
```

and building a directory of the wheels for my current packages and all their dependencies.

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir=/tmp/wheelhouse .
```

However I would like to also build wheels for all the packages listed in any of the packages tests_require.

Obviously I could explicitly specify the requirements in a duplicate test_requirements.txt file:

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir=/mnt/wheelhouse -r test-requirements.txt
```

But then I am duplicating the dependencies in both the test requirements file and in the tests_require list.  I could read the test requirements file into the tests_require but that seems to be misusing requirements files which to my understanding are intended to allow users to be in control of specifying an environment of packages that are known to work together.

```
Requirements files - http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/cookbook.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no explicit support for this. The easiest way to do this would be to add, an `extra` to your setup.py:

```
setup(
    extras_require={
        "test": ["pytest", "your other requirements"],
    },
)
```

You can of course reuse the same `list` as for `test_requires`, then you can `pip wheel .[test]` and it will make wheels for all of those.

Comment: Is the syntax "pip wheel .[test]" suppose to work on python-2.7? I get a :  "zsh: no matches found: [test]"

Comment: You probably just need to quote '.[test]' so that it doesn't try to search for filenames matching that shell wildcard pattern.